# What does "useinbandfec is a unidirectional receive-only parameter" mean in Opus?

Tags: c++, audio, codec, opus

I am trying to implement a Opus transcoder in C++, and I have some conceptual questions.
As for the useinbandfec parameter, I don't quite understand the meaning of "unidirectional receive-only parameter", as written in [RFC7587, section 7.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7587#page-15):

> The "useinbandfec" parameter is a unidirectional receive-only
> parameter.

For example, Alice is calling Bob. Alice uses Opus codec with useinbandfec=1, while Bob doesn't use Opus. Therefore, there should be a Opus transcoder between the two. If so, how can I configure the settings of Opus encoder and decoder?

As for Alice->Bob where `opus_decode()` is needed, what value should be sent as the 5th parameter (fecFlag)? And as for Bob->Alice where a Opus encoder is needed, what value should be sent with `OPUS_SET_INBAND_FEC()` in `opus_encoder_ctl()`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Parameter useinbandfec**

This parameter means that encoder puts additional information to the stream to recover lost packets. How it works, when encoder encodes number N+1 packet it add there some information about packet N that is useful for decoder if it supports recovery.

If decoder does not support recovery then this information is useless and wasting bandwidth.

**Unidirectional receive only parameter meaning**

This means that if you specify it in session descriptor (SDP) then this parameters describes capability of receiver and advise sender to use or not to use inbound FEC

**Questions:**

**1**

> For example, Alice is calling Bob. Alice uses Opus codec with
>   useinbandfec=1, while Bob doesn't use Opus. Therefore, there should be
>   a Opus transcoder between the two. If so, how can I configure the
>   settings of Opus encoder and decoder?

In this configuration you need transcoder between Alice and Bob. If transcoder supports FEC you may prefer to include useinbandfec=1 to SDP fmtp attribute. If encoder (sender on Alice device) is also under your control you MAY set ask encoder to add FEC to the stream in following condtions:

- Losses in network (may be detected by RTCP)
- Transcoder capability to decode it (may be known from SDP parameter)

**2**

> As for Alice->Bob where opus_decode() is needed, what value should be
>   sent as the 5th parameter (fecFlag)?

opus_decode FEC flag is used when you detect packet loss (for example by RTP sequence number). Lets assume that you receive packet N and N-1 packet is lost. Then you may restore packet N-1 by calling opus_decode with fecFlag set to true and then decode packet N:

```
packets[N-1] = decode_opus(pktN, fecFlag=true)
packets[N]   = decode_opus(pktN, fecFlag=false)
```

**3**

> And as for Bob->Alice where a Opus encoder is needed, what value
>   should be sent with OPUS_SET_INBAND_FEC() in opus_encoder_ctl()?

OPUS_SET_INBAND_FEC is better to set from useinbandfec parameter retrieved from Alice SDP. Also beware that FEC is not included into encoded stream unless you do not set [OPUS_SET_PACKET_LOSS_PERC](http://opus-codec.org/docs/opus_api-1.2/group__opus__encoderctls.html#gafda1c951dea919ba54432cd03827f1a9)

Comment: If FEC is enabled, shouldn't the fecFlag in question 2 be the other way round, according to [opus_demo.c](https://github.com/gcp/opus/blob/master/src/opus_demo.c#L777)? When decoding pktN-1, we go through line 785, and when decoding pktN, we go through line 781?

Comment: opus_demo code is pretty messy. I think statement that FEC is added to subsequent packet is good proof that you need packet N FEC data to recovery packet N-1: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6716#section-2.1.7
But if you do not believe you can add some print to OPUS demo and check how it works